# Extended searchbar closes when autofilled

Tags: jquery, html, css, autofill

I made an extended searchbar with html5, css3 and jquery. My problem is that when the browser autofills any content and you submit, the searchbar just closes instead of submitting.

This is my code.

```js
$('.searchbox-input').prop('required', 'true');
$(document).ready(function () {
    var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
    var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
    var searchbox = $('.searchbox');
    var isOpen = false;
    submitIcon.click(function () {
        if (!isOpen) {
            searchbox.addClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focus();
            isOpen = true;
        } else {
            searchbox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
            inputBox.focusout();
            isOpen = false;
        }
    });

    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        buttonUp();
    });


    submitIcon.mouseup(function () {
        return false;
    });
    searchbox.mouseup(function () {
        return false;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        if (isOpen) {
            $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
            submitIcon.click();
        }
    });
});

function buttonUp() {
    var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
    inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;

    if (inputVal !== 0) {
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.searchbox-input').val('');
        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

```css
/* Searchbar */
 .container {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    right: 200px;
}
.searchbox {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.searchbox-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: #313132;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #efefef;
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
    font-family: Comfortaa, Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.searchbox-input:focus {
    outline-style:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border-color:transparent;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #808080;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #808080;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #808080;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #808080;
}
.searchbox-icon, .searchbox-submit {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #313132;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #4BC599;
}
.searchbox {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 40px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.1s;
    -0-transition: width 0.1s;
    transition: width 0.1s;
}
.searchbox-open {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form action="" class="searchbox">
        <input type="text" class="searchbox-input" placeholder="Enter search term" name="search" id="search">
        <button type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" value=""><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button> <span class="searchbox-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>

    </form>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me.

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Your fiddle is just missing jQuery!
> http://jsfiddle.net/g1qtaoy9/2/

Answer (score 0):

In order for your example to work properly you must declare that you need to use jQuery by selecting it in the top left corner.

The issue with your code is that the submit button is never actually pressed because it is underneath the icon button. This fiddle should work

http://jsfiddle.net/g1qtaoy9/3/

Basically I just manually trigger the submit when the time is right

```
submitIcon.click(function () {
    if (!isOpen) {
        searchbox.addClass('searchbox-open');
        inputBox.focus();

        isOpen = true;
    } else {
        searchbox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
        inputBox.focusout();
        searchbox.submit();
        isOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Never mind, it doenst work correctly yet. Now it is submitting even if you click anywhere on the page. 
The idea was: If you click once the searchbar opens, 
second click closes it, if there is no content in the input. Clicking anywhere on the page will close it as well.
If there is content in it, it will submit by clicking on the Submit button again.